# Default tests don't work in a new React Native 0.59.10

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, settings, setup-project

I need to use a old React Native version (0.59.10)

When I init a new project like this

`npx react-native-cli init rnTestTest --version 0.59.10`

and then I run the test `yarn test`

the error is:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'setupDevtools' from 'node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:3:15)
```

Why is there this error?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a proper solution for this issue.
I expected that running from scratch a new react-native template it would have made the test run.

What I've done is to downgrade jest. So now in the devDependencies I have this versions:

```
    ...
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    ...
```